# Can I restrict Calibre to import books without name modification

Tags: ebook, kindle, calibre, ereader

Currently if I Add Book to calibre library it adds book by its "book" name not file name.

For example I have downloaded bunch of books which are prefixed by year like "1953 - Some Book", when I add those to calibre library I got "Some Book"

I really want to use it to convert epub to mobi. So after conversion I have physical files which are "Some Book" - the year prefixes are all lost..

Hence I cant read them in correct sequence.

Is there a way to setup Calibre to use physical file names instead?

Answer (score 2):

This question was asked in 2016. Now, in 2019, there does exist a sophisticated feature to customize a book's saved file name and even directory path. Under `preferences`, look for the section `saving books to disk`, and see that you are provided with the opportunity to create what they call a "template" to customize the file and directory name by any combination of metadata.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Calibre to change their original names of the books so that you can get the books with changed name. Otherwise, these convert e-reader tools will identify the books by their real name, not the file names you changed personally.

Comment: Can you explain to OP how to do it?